# Bootstrap Nav Bar problems

Tags: navbar

I am having trouble with my nav bar, the first link in the nav bar is always to low. There seems to be a hidden `<a>` tag in it that I can not remove. This wasnt there until I added a link to the logo on the left. When the logo was not a link the first link stayed in the correct position. I have uploaded some of the code to codepen

https://codepen.io/BitRot86/pen/qXgQzE

Any ideas would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two small typo mistakes in your HTML code.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navLeft">
    <li>
        @*<a href="index.php"><img src="http://gbcsite.ca/v5/images/GBC-logo.png" class="img-responsive" width="200px"><a />*@
        <a href="index.php">
            <img src="http://gbcsite.ca/v5/images/GBC-logo.png" class="img-responsive" width="200" />
            </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

First, you've not closed the `<img>` tag.

Second, you've incorrectly closed `<a>` tag under image link.

I've fixed it at my end and it is working.

Comment: Thank you, I keep missing typos in my text. I read over it a couple times and kept missing it. Thank you for find it for me!!